# Altium PCB layout: Measure points

Tags: altium

[image: Example of how kicad displays differential data]

Cntl + M: Will get you a measurement tool however I wish to make faster measurements.

In kiCad, you can press space bar and it gives a 0,0 origin reference measurment to the cursor. (Displayed on the UI)

Is there such a feature in Altium, I need quicker measurement references than the cumbersome measure tool.

**Solved**

**Shift + D** changes the heads up view to add dx dy measurement and **INSERT** zeros the dx dy origin point to your cursor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In altium, the heads up display shows the dx and dy from wherever you last clicked. Show the heads up display with Shift+H.

It has something called hotspot snap where it attempts to guess the thing you are interested in when clicking, for calculating the hotspot origin. Ie if you click on a via 1 mil off the center, it will think that you actually want the via itself and will set the hotspot origin at the exact center of it.

If you want more precise measurements then you'll need to either move the origin or jot down the locations of things and do the math.

There are also some other options you can play with in View > Board Insight

[image: Heads up display]

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! 

Just to add to this, Shift + D changes the heads up view to add dx dy

and INSERT zeros the dx dy point

Answer (score 2):

> In kiCad, you can press space bar and it gives a 0,0 origin reference measurment to the cursor. (Displayed on the UI)

This information is always displayed in Altium, as far as I know. You don't even have to push a single key to get it. Look in the lower-left corner of the screen:

[image]

Comment: This is the coordinate of the cursor to the origin. Im looking for the relative coordinate to a selected point.

Comment: See image in post :)

Comment: @KieranDuggan, you can move the origin to any place you like...somewhere in the "Edit" menu, IIRC.

Comment: Moving the origin does not seem to be the most healthy option here. It can be moved to reference anything. But for very quick measurements it removes the context of where you are measuring. Which is a hassle.

Comment: @KieranDuggan, it sounds like the best solution to your problem is just to use KiCad instead of Altium.